# R merge a particular column from one data frame to another according to its reference column

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am a beginner R user.
I have two huge dataframes and I want to add new column called Vaccine at hkdata.2, which the data is taken from another DF adherence according to 2 reference columns at hkdata.2 (hhID and member), could someone please help me?

```
hkdata.2
hhID    member  T0  delta   X_hh    X_fm    ILI age
1          1    7      0    0       0        0  44
1          2    7      0    0       0        0  36
2          1    8      0    1       0        0  39
2          2    8      0    1       0        0  39

adherence
hhID member mask soap vaccine
1      0      1    0    1   
1      1      1    1    1
1      2      0    0    1
2      0      1    0    0
2      1      0    0    0
2      2      1    0    1
```

So at the end I can get something like this.
With an extra column called vaccine in hkdata.2

```
hkdata.2
hhID    member  T0  delta   X_hh    X_fm    ILI age vaccine
1          1    7      0    0       0        0  44    1
1          2    7      0    0       0        0  36    1
2          1    8      0    1       0        0  39    0
2          2    8      0    1       0        0  39    1
```

Comment: Please check ?merge(), ?rbind_list from dplyr.  Here, the columns `hhID`, `member` are not unique in both the dataset.

Comment: so under the same hhID, there is only 1 unique # of member

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Using `v1.9.6` for `on=` syntax. See history for old code.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(hkdata.2)[setDT(adherence), vaccine := i.vaccine, on=c("hhID", "member")]
#    hhID member T0 delta X_hh X_fm ILI age vaccine
# 1:    1      1  7     0    0    0   0  44       1
# 2:    1      2  7     0    0    0   0  36       1
# 3:    2      1  8     0    1    0   0  39       0
# 4:    2      2  8     0    1    0   0  39       1
```

1. `setDT` converts a data.frame to data.table *by reference*.
2. Perform the join on columns specified by `on=`. `Note that this join is both a) fast *and* b) memory efficient. a) *fast* because they're binary search based joins, and no copy is being made here at all. The`vaccine`column is directly added to your`hkdata.2`data.table. b) *memory efficient* because only the column`vaccine` that you require is  used in the join, and not the other columns (which is particularly great to have on really large datasets).

---

Here's a benchmark assuming 100,000 `hhID`s and 200 `member`s within each `hhID`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6
require(dplyr) # 0.4.3.9000

set.seed(98192L)
N = 40e6 # 40 million rows
hkdata.2 = data.frame(hhID   = rep(1:1e5, each=200), 
                      member = 1:200,
                      T0     = sample(10),
                      delta  = sample(0:1), 
                      X_hh   = sample(0:1), 
                      X_fm   = sample(0:1), 
                      ILI    = sample(0:1),
                      age    = sample(30:100, N/2, TRUE))

# let's go with 100,000 hhIDs and 400 members here:
adherence = data.frame(hhID    = rep(1:1e5, each=400), 
                       member  = 1:400,
                       mask    = sample(0:1),
                       soap    = sample(0:1),
                       vaccine = sample(0:1))

## dplyr timing
system.time(ans1 <- left_join(hkdata.2, select(adherence, -soap, -mask)))
#   user  system elapsed
# 16.977   2.163  19.605
## data.table timing
system.time(setDT(hkdata.2)[setDT(adherence), vaccine := i.vaccine, on=c("hhID", "member")])
#   user  system elapsed
#  1.186   0.233   1.427
```

The peak memory usage of `dplyr` was 4.7GB and took 19.6 seconds to complete, whereas `data.table` took 1.4 seconds with peak memory usage of 2.2GB.

> Summary: `data.table` is ~14x faster and ~2.1x memory efficient here.

Comment: Do you need `setDT(adherence)`?

Comment: Yes. If not, at the moment, we use as.data.table() which would result in a copy.

Comment: So `setDT(hkdata.2)[adherence, vaccine := i.vaccine, on=c("hhID", "member")]` isn't recommended?

Comment: If `adherence`is small, not an issue.

Comment: Quick question - what if I would like to merge *more* than one column?

Answer (score 3):

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(hkdata.2, adherence)
 #    Joining by: c("hhID", "member")
 #  hhID member T0 delta X_hh X_fm ILI age mask soap vaccine
 #1    1      1  7     0    0    0   0  44    1    1       1
 #2    1      2  7     0    0    0   0  36    0    0       1
 #3    2      1  8     0    1    0   0  39    0    0       0
 #4    2      2  8     0    1    0   0  39    1    0       1
```

If you don't need `mask`, `soap`

```
  left_join(hkdata.2, adherence) %>% select(-soap, -mask)
```

Or

```
  left_join(hkdata.2, adherence[,c("hhID", "member", "vaccine")])
```

Comment: cause when i type view(hkdata.2), it is still not showing in the dataframe.

Comment: @user3848693. Suppose you store the results in `res <- left_join(hkdata.2,....)`, can you check the `str(res)`. Also, I suppose `hkdata.2` is one of your input datasets..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `plyr` library to do this.

```
library(plyr)
new_frame=join(hkdata.2,adherence,by=c('hhID','member'))
```

Comment: Is it possible that just to merge the vaccine column to the dataframe?

Comment: Yeah, you can subset the adherence data frame to only have the ID variables and the vaccine variable.  Then it will only attach those.